# out of memory exception when reading image from folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

i need to read all image files from folder ans save it to another folder with compressed size.However my code  compresses this images very well but it give error after 695 image files "out of memory exception". This my code.there are around 2000 images

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();
files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("../imgres") + "\\products\\", "*.jpg").ToList();
for (int k = 0; k < files.Count; k++)
{
  if (File.Exists(files[k].ToString()))
  {
    string SaveLocation1 = "";
    System.Drawing.Image thumbnail;
    System.Drawing.Image smallsize;
    System.Drawing.Image originalimg;

    originalimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(files[k].ToString());
    thumbnail = originalimg.GetThumbnailImage(110, 110, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero);
    smallsize = originalimg.GetThumbnailImage(47, 47, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero);

    SaveLocation1 = Server.MapPath("../imgres/products") + "\\Thumbnail\\" + Path.GetFileName(files[k].ToString());
    thumbnail.Save(SaveLocation1);
    thumbnail.Dispose();

    SaveLocation1 = Server.MapPath("../imgres/products") + "\\smallsize\\" + Path.GetFileName(files[k].ToString());
    smallsize.Save(SaveLocation1);
    smallsize.Dispose();

  }
}
```

Comment: You don't call `Dispose` on `originalimg` and you're running out of memory? [Hm...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: Try to call `originalimg.Dispose();` also.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108607/out-of-memory-exception-on-system-drawing-image-fromfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are not disposing `originalimg` like you are with the other image references. You should add the following at the end of your if statement:

```
originalimg.Dispose();
```

I would however recommend you use `using` blocks, these will help you better manage the disposing of such resources as you won't have to implicitly call the `Dispose` method, and it will also handle the dispose even if an exception occurring before your call to `Dispose`, so you can be sure it will be cleaned up correctly.

Something like this:

```
if (File.Exists(files[k].ToString()))
{
    using(System.Drawing.Image originalimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(files[k].ToString()))
    {
        using(System.Drawing.Image thumbnail = originalimg.GetThumbnailImage(110, 110, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            using(System.Drawing.Image smallsize = originalimg.GetThumbnailImage(47, 47, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                string SaveLocation1 = Server.MapPath("../imgres/products") + "\\Thumbnail\\" + Path.GetFileName(files[k].ToString());
                thumbnail.Save(SaveLocation1);

                SaveLocation1 = Server.MapPath("../imgres/products") + "\\smallsize\\" + Path.GetFileName(files[k].ToString());
                smallsize.Save(SaveLocation1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply guys,problem was with corrupt image some of images were corrupt.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to modify this with a using block, to avoid any need to call (or forget to call) the `Dispose` method:

```
using (Image originalimg = Image.FromFile(files[k].ToString()))
{
   using (Image thumbnail = originalimg.GetThumbnailImage(110, 110, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero))
   {
      thumbnail.Save(...);
   }

   using (Image smallsize = originalimg.GetThumbnailImage(47, 47, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero))
   {
      smallsize.Save(...);
   }
}
```

Comment: Even if you don't forget to call it, an exception might get in the way. You should always be ... using `using` #nopunintended.

Comment: Thanks for reply guys,problem was with corrupt image some of images were corrupt.