# C# Win. Form - Out of memory when retrieving an Image

Tags: c#, winforms, out-of-memory, .net-3.5

### Brief

I want to display a PNG image in my PictureBox. At runtime the software asks the path of the image from the user.

### Solution i am using

This is my code uptill now

```
picturebox1.Image = null;
OpenFileDialog ofDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
ofDlg.Filter = "Image files|*.png";
if (DialogResult.OK == ofDlg.ShowDialog())
{
     picturebox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofDlg.FileName); //Out of memory.
}
```

### Problem

It was all working fine uptill now untill i got an image which was of **25.7 MB (8827 x 11350 pixels)**.

I know you might all suggest that i should get a lighter version of this image BUT the problem is that this software is used to zoom the image to view the image in detail. So i cannot resize it at any cost.

Now whenever i run the above code it gives me the exception

> Out of memory.

I do not understand what is the problem here because i have **8GB of RAM installed** on my PC then how it is out of memory? Below is my CPU usage at the time when this error message appeared.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the complete stack from your exception?

Comment: Your app is no longer in the process list there..

Comment: @BugFinder it is on number 5

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108607/out-of-memory-exception-on-system-drawing-image-fromfile

Comment: The image is about 286MiB of pixel data if 24-bit.

Comment: @Smartis i cant because even after applying a try catch the error pops up on the `picturebox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofDlg.FileName);` line

Comment: Is it compiled to x64?

Comment: @PepitoSh the software is compiled in x64.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen that may be the case but i have 4 GB of free space at that partciular point of time.

Comment: Sadly the bitmap is not 24 but 32 bit to start with - alpha channel and staying to a "sane" byte layout for the graphics card mandates 32 bit bitmaps. And you need this memory without interruption which is HARD for a 32 bit program to get.

Comment: Perhaps, but perhaps not 286 *continuous* available space, or 382 if 32-bit.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen so what shall i do ? i cant re-arrange RAM memory allocation (out of my skill level)

Comment: LOH could be fragmented.

Comment: @PepitoSh LOH? and how to fragement it?

Comment: You should use a tool to convert the image into a format suitable for random access to the pixels, and rewrite your program accordingly.

Comment: Or implement the loading yourself so that you don't need continuous memory.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen do you know how to read a part of the image? i will try to read it part by part and apply some algo on it

Comment: @PepitoSh my bad it is compiled on x86

Comment: No, I don't, you're likely going to have to find a 3rd party library to help you

Comment: From .net 4.5.1: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mariohewardt/2013/06/26/no-more-memory-fragmentation-on-the-net-large-object-heap/

Comment: @Agent_Spock - Does this error occur the first time you load this image or does it work for a while before the error?

Comment: @Enigmativity after a while.....btw "The General"'s solution worked but trying to figure out why?

Comment: @Agent_Spock - I would think you are running out of O/S graphic handles. When they run out they report as an out of memory error even though you have heaps of memory free. There are just a limited number of handles and disposing releases them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the sugestions of all the comments, i.e Make sure you are in 64 bit

But you need to also make sure you are disposing your images or you will run out of memory sooner or later anyway. The following is just an exmaple

```
if(picturebox1.Image != null)
   picturebox1.Image.Dispose();

picturebox1.Image = null;

OpenFileDialog ofDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
ofDlg.Filter = "Image files|*.png";
if (DialogResult.OK == ofDlg.ShowDialog())
{
     picturebox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofDlg.FileName); //Out of memory.
}
```

Comment: this actually worked BUT i do not understand why it worked? was it keeping every image in the memory that has been set to picturebox? because i never saw increment of RAM usage after every image view.

Comment: @Agent_Spock Yeah a lot of bad things happen when you dont dispose images, first is a big memory leak, however the second is that you have unmanaged file handles and such hanging around if you read them from disk

Comment: sorry i am not a professinal like you but how "unmanaged file handles" still lurk around when i have changed my image?

Comment: Because the image keeps a reference to them from the operating system until you dispose them and it cleans it self up. by not disposing you are never allowing the image to clean itself up, things are'nt going out of memory in a variety of different ways

Comment: It's not a memory issue, it's a O/S graphics handle issue.

Comment: GDI Process Handles to be precise.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah gdi handle, file handle, any managed memory, however yeah the out of memory is gdi